# How to delete an IfStmt with clangs Rewriter, when the if only surrounds one statement, that is decided with a preprocessor if construct

Tags: c++, clang, preprocessor

While writing my thesis I needed to delete an IfStmt in a C++ file with clang Rewriter.

I use clang and its AST because I need the AST to find the correct location. For deletion, I use the `getSourceRange` method of the if construction and then I delete it with the appropriate method of the Rewriter.

But after doing this I got an syntax error in the changed C++ file.

The if looks like:

```
if( someCondition )
#if SOMEOTHERCONDITION
doSth1();
#else
doSth2();
#endif
```

After the deletion, the if-part of the preprocessor construct was deleted and the rest of it remained.

Is there any common way to deal with such a problem?

Comment: What should the source look like after removing the if?

Comment: in this case i would like to delete the complete preprocessor construct to avoid the syntax error described above.

Comment: It would even be better to only delete line 1, 3 and 5 because then only the statements that depend on the if construct from line 1 would be deleted.